# Powershell find subfolders or files under a folder, exclude specific users and include full control

Tags: powershell

#### Logic & Expected result:

E.g, Folder like :

```
A
    B(user1[(F)],user2[(F)],user3[(M)])
    C(user1[(F)],user2[(F)],user3[(F)])
    D(user1[(F)],user2[(F)],user3[(M)])
```

input `somecli --path "A" --exclude-users "user1,user2"` retrun result like :

```
B[user3(F)]
```

#### What I've tried:

I tried `icacls folder path`, like:

```
PS C:\Users\weihanadmin> icacls "D:\SomeFolder\*"
D:\SomeFolder\ERP NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 HCTKENT\GMO:(OI)(CI)(M)
                 HCTKENT\PMC:(OI)(CI)(RX)
                 BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 HCTKENT\ITadmin:(OI)(CI)(F)

D:\SomeFolder\Bus NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
               HCTKENT\Bus:(OI)(CI)(F)
               BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
               HCTKENT\ITadmin:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

I know `(F)` means `full controll`, then I don't know what should I do to advance to further

Comment: By "exclude specific users" do you mean file owners or what?

Comment: @ZoranJankov like example, user1 has (F) permission, but I want to exclude it.

Comment: Try [FileSystemAccessRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instead, there are several questions in SO about its usage.